# Why do I keep getting this ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models that have a has_many association to the same object. I have a User, an Admin, and Visits.

Users has_many Visits
Admins has_many Visits

Every time I create a Visit with a User it works, but when I do it with an Admin it gives me an error:

`ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch`.

The full error is this:

`User(#70282715553200) expected, got #<Admin id: 2, email: "admin@gmail.com", created_at: "2019-02-07 12:08:40", updated_at: "2019-02-07 12:08:40"> which is an instance of Admin(#70282709528720)`

```
def create
  @visit = @service.visits.new(visit_params)

  if user_signed_in?
    @visit.user = current_user
  else
    @visit.user = current_admin
  end

  if @visit.save
    redirect_to service_visits_path(@service)
  else
    redirect_to @services
  end

end
```

==============================

```
class Admin < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and 
  # :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :visits, dependent: :destroy
end
```

==============================

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and 
  #  :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :visits, dependent: :destroy
end
```

==============================

```
class Visit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :admin
  belongs_to :service
end
```

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? There should only be one version tagged (3 or 4)

Comment: It was supposed to be just version 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you've got some kind of polymorphism going on, which isn't documented, I'd try and change this:

```
if user_signed_in?
  @visit.user = current_user
else
  @visit.user = current_admin
end
```

To this:

```
if user_signed_in?
  @visit.user = current_user
else
  @visit.admin = current_admin # this line
end
```

Your `Visit` model says a visit has both one `User`, and one `Admin`, so you have to assign the current_admin to the `@visit.admin`, not `@visit.user`.

If you're using Rails 5, you'll also need to update your model as below:

```
class Visit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  belongs_to :admin, optional: true
  belongs_to :service
end
```

As I note in my comment below, the suggestion from @bo-oz should be given considerable consideration. I haven't seen User and Admin tables typically split out as you've done in production applications. The concept of 'admin' is typically handled as a separate `Role` model (the rolify gem is good for this), or more simply as a boolean on the `User` model.

Comment: Thanks for replying to my solution. I agree that there might be a use-case, but until proven differently in 99% of the cases there isn't. Your solution won't work, because there will always be a missing relationship, either User or Admin. Since Rails 5 belongs_to relations are mandatory, so the answer should at least include some way to deal with that (setting optional: true parameter)

Comment: This is true, I forgot about the optional: `true` for rails 5, but this post is tagged rails 3 & rails 4. I'll update it to note that, however. I'm also going to put an update on mine pointing to yours because I'm in agreement that the "best" solution involves re-thinking whether they need a separate table for admins (they probably don't)

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked perfectly! However, due to the admin and user being completely different users with different dashboards and functionality. So this works perfectly for me.

Comment: They both breath the same oxygen right? So they are all the same.... the fact that they have different abilities, shouldn't be of the User models Concern.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do us just plain wrong. An Admin is a User as well. You should remove the Admin model entirely. If you need to assign additional capabilities / rights to someone, you should either create an additional attribute (admin boolean yes/no), or create some kind of Role Based model. Have a look at Rolify gem.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and 
:omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :visits, dependent: :destroy

  def is_admin?
    // return true if user is admin
  end
 end

class Visit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :service
end

def create
@visit = @service.visits.new(visit_params)

if user_signed_in?
  @visit.user = current_user
else

if @visit.save
  redirect_to service_visits_path(@service)
else
  redirect_to @services
end
```

One warning though.... the user is mandatory is this relationship, so this would break if someone is not logged in! Think about it... either don't create a Visit, or create an Anonynous visit.

Comment: I think you got downvoted (it wasn't me) because you're making assumptions about how the user needs to structure/model their user/admin. While I nearly 100% agree that a User is a User and roles should be separated some other way (as you noted, thru a boolean or rolify), there might be a use case where the OP needs to split them up.

Comment: True, although you must agree that those assumptions hold true 99/100... I think these questions should be seen as opportunities to teach good practice, instead of assuming that an apparent newbie has come up with a use-case that justifies this design choice.